# Is dynamic polymorphism a overhead in this scenario?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, static-polymorphism

I am trying to model some database related functionalities through c++ inheritance.
There are around 150 tables in the database. And these tables fall into specific groups and tables within a specific group can be manipulated (querying, writing, etc) in a similar way.

```
class BaseTable(){
//Functionalities common for all tables. Eg: a create_table method.
}

class Group1Table(): BaseTable{
//Inherits from BaseTable and overrides(virtual function) or adds new functionlities.
}

class Group2Table(): BaseTable{
//Inherits from BaseTable and overrides(virtual function) or adds new functionlities.
}
```

There could be more GroupTables and the inheritance can also go deeper levels.

With this kind of inheritance, I can initialize a map like this:

```
std::map<int, boost::shared_ptr<BaseTable> > tablesMap = boost::assign::map_list_of(1, new BaseTable(x,y,z))(2, new Group1Table(p, q, r) ....(150, new GroupXTable(a, b, c)
```

So tablesMap would have a map of all the 150 tables (I have used simple keys in ascending order for simplicity. But the keys could be different. Hence the use of maps instead of a vector). With this map, I can iterate and call things like x->create_table(), x->query(), etc. Or when I want to do specific action on a specific table I can simply call

```
tablesMap[key]->action()
```

and the polymorphism will take care of calling the right function.

My concern is whether there is an overhead of storing these dynamically polymorphic objects and using it like the way I have described above. Or am I just being paranoid? Note that there will always be fixed number of objects in the map initialized once (~150 equal to the number of tables) and I would iterate through these objects and call various virtual functions wherever needed.

Is there a better way to model the problem so that I can avoid virtual functions? I tried to think in the lines of CRTP (static polymorphism) but I couldn't figure out a way to put the objects in a map and iterate through them like I can do with dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: Lookup in the map is going to cost more than the dynamic dispatch

Comment: am I just being paranoid? - yes =)

Comment: Dynamic polymorphism is **always** an overhead. Question is, if it's significant for your use case. That I'd answer with 'No' here.

Comment: Unless you have very specific performance requirements that are in jeopardy from an execution standpoint, your concern is verging on PMO --- Pre-Mature Optimization.  Your design has many merits.  Make it work *right* and then determine if performance is an issue.  Most people create horrible things by succumbing to PMO and most of the time it is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: It's true that dynamic polymorphism is more expensive than a non-polymorphic function call, but that isn't really a fair comparison. You're considering polymorphism because you need different objects to have different variations on the same behavior. Compared to other ways of getting varying behavior (e.g. if-else chain, jump table, etc.), you'll probably have a hard time building something more efficient than the virtual function mechanism.